# How to make a 3D plot over a triangular region

Tags: plotting

I'm new to mathematica. 
I'm trying to `Plot3D` the function `f[x_,y_]:=x^3+2x y` over the triangular region of the plane with vertices `{-4,-1}` and `{0,3}` and `{4,-1}`, then Plot the surface and its tangent plane at the point `{1,2}`

I tried everything, but I but I can't ever get the triangular region.

Thanks,

Comment: You mean `Plot3D[x^3+2 x y,{x,y}\[Element]Triangle[{{-4,-1},{0,3},{4,-1}}],ClippingStyle->None]`?

Comment: If you get the answer.You can click the mark to choice you answer for your post [like this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-06-14-12-58-43.png) 
.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following Option:

```
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},y<3-x&&y>-1&&y<3+x]
```

Or, use this for x and y's region spexification:

```
{x,y}\[Element]Triangle[{{-4,-1},{4,-1},{0,3}}]
```

Of course, you'll have to change the functions accodingly in different situations.

Answer (score 2):

As you first question I have give solution [in the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118367/newbie-using-mathematica#comment319873_118367),I have repeat it here

```
Plot3D[x^3 + 2 x y, {x, y} \[Element] 
  Triangle[{{-4, -1}, {0, 3}, {4, -1}}], ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

---

As your second question I call the `Wolfram alpha` to cope with it.

```
WolframAlpha["tangent plane to x^3 + 2 x y at (x, y) = (1, 2)",{{"Plot",1},"Content"}]
```

[image]

Actually I should leave your question alone and give it a tag of too board,but you are a first time to `Mathematica SE`.Anyway welcome to here. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to plot. You can use regions in `Plot3D`. You can use `RegionFunction` as an option in `Plot3D`. You can implicitly define the region. In the following I show some ways (and one way to show tangent plane to point of interest).

Setup:

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + 2 x y;
tg = Triangle[{{-4, -1}, {0, 3}, {4, -1}}];
rmf = RegionMember[tg, {x, y}];
ir = ImplicitRegion[{rmf}~
    Join~{z < f[x, y]}, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 3}, {z, -60, 60}}];
tg3 = Triangle[{##, -60} & @@@ tg[[1]]];
poi = {1, 2, f[1, 2]};
grd = Grad[f[x, y] - z, {x, y, z}] /. {x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> f[x, y]};
```

Visualization:

```
rp3 = RegionPlot3D[ir, PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]];
p3 = Plot3D[x^3 + 2 x y, {x, y} \[Element] tg, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotRange -> {-60, 60}];
t3 = Graphics3D[{Red, tg3, Purple, PointSize[0.02], Point[poi]}];
plane = ContourPlot3D[
   grd.({x, y, z} - poi) == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 3}, {z, -10, 10}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.6], Mesh -> None];
Show[rp3, p3, t3, plane]
```

[image]